# Get LinkedIn user href on list (Selenium)

Tags: python, list, selenium, linkedin-api

I'm beginner to Python & Selenium, I am just trying to get all LinkedIn profile `href`s on specific page with Selenium for adding to a list but I don't know why it returns all same URL 10 times:

[image]

[image]

This is my code:

```py
try:
    browser.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(email_address)
    sleep(1)
    browser.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
    sleep(1)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn__primary--large from__button--floating']").click()
    sleep(1)

    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "global-nav")))
    sleep(0.5)
    browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?geoUrn=%5B%22104246759%22%2C%2290009659%22%2C%22106383538%22%5D&keywords=mark%20johnson&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER')
    
    user = []
    url = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='app-aware-link']")
    
    for i in range(10):
        href = url[i].get_attribute('href')
        user.append(href)
        print(user)

except Exception as e:
     traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Did you print out ```url``` to make sure it is finding distinct elements? It appears that there are multiples of that xpath that have the same url.

Comment: However, i thinking my a-tag "app-aware-link" come make a distinct element :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the xpath is matching multiple elements with the same href. You could make a list of unique hrefs:

```
user = []
url = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='app-aware-link']")
unique_hrefs = []
[unique_hrefs.append(x.get_attribute('href')) for x in url if x.get_attribute('href') not in unique_hrefs]

for i in unique_hrefs:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Sorry my bad,, i want each "URL" of all user on this page